# How to put those things next to eachother? CSS

Tags: html, css, web

basically my website looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VQ8X.png
I want to put that container with text in it next to the image. How can I do that, and keep it centered? I'll put my code below.

```
<body>
<div style="width:200px; height:516px; opacity:0.8; margin: 0px auto;"><a href="#" id="clickable_div"><img style="-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 1px rgba(183,183,183, 0.4); -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 1px rgba(183,183,183, 0.4); box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 1px rgba(183,183,183, 0.4);" src="media/images/logo.png"></a></div>
<div id="nav_menu" style="display:none; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72); width:300px; margin: 0px auto;">
  <center>Endless Void></center>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please not use the `<center>` tag as it is depreciated and support for it by browsers could be dropped at anytime.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not an answer for my question.

Comment: Its a comment and not meant to be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will more than likely have to use:

```
margin: 0 auto;
width: /* your width here */
```

to center your content along with either floating your two DIVs or absolutely positioning them.

When using `margin: 0 auto;` you **need** to supply a width value or it will not work as once the browser has a width to work with it can auto calculate the margins for you. You can apply `margin: 0 auto` to the `<body>` tag or a another wrapping element like a `<div>` that contains your image and text DIVs.

A `<div>` is a block level element that will try to take up the whole width of the page by default. That is why you need to [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) them or use some kind of [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) that changes that behavior and get the two elements to line up next to one another.

Here is a basic example in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vn34bw84/

Answer (score 0):

Simply by adding `inline-block` and using a container:

```css
#container {
    text-align:center;
}

#container > div {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div style="width:200px; height:516px; opacity:0.8; margin: 0px auto;"><a href="#" id="clickable_div"><img style="-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 1px rgba(183,183,183, 0.4); -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 1px rgba(183,183,183, 0.4); box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 1px rgba(183,183,183, 0.4);" src="media/images/logo.png"/></a>

    </div>
    <div id="nav_menu" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72); width:300px; margin: 0px auto;">
        Endless Void
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your CSS file:

```
#container {width: 200px;}
#left { border: 1px dotted red; float: left;  padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
#right { border: 1px dotted red; float: right; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
/* I have added the border it usually helps to know where each boxes during development then later remove it. Also use padding and margin to get what you want */
```

And this in your HTML body

```
   <div id='container'>
         <div id='left'>
         </div>
         <div id='right'>
         </div>
   </div>
```